# Can ternary work with return and print in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, return, function, ternary

Ternary is easy to use when checking for none-y variables.

```
>>> x = None
>>> y = 2 if x else 3
>>> y
3
```

If i want to check for none-ity before i return is there a ternary equivalence to:

```
def foobar(x):
  if x:
    return x*x
  else:
    print 'x is None-y'
```

Is there something that looks like:

```
def foobar(x):
  return x*x if x else print 'x is None-y'
```

Comment: Don't do that in real programs. Python ain't Ruby. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `print` as a function, import it from `__future__` in Python2:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> def foobar(x):
      return x*x if x else print ('x is None-y')
... 
>>> foobar(0)
x is None-y
>>> foobar(2)
4
```

Another alternative will be to use `sys.stdout`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> def foobar(x):
      return x*x if x else sys.stdout.write('x is None-y\n')
... 
>>> foobar(0)
x is None-y
>>> foobar(2)
4
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, `print` is a statement and cannot be used within a conditional expression.

In Python 3, `print` is a function and therefore can be used like this (with parentheses). However, I'd argue that this is poor style since `print()` is called for its side effect rather than return value.

I'd stick with the original `if` (possibly adding an explicit `return` to the `else` for clarity).

Finally, your code claims that `0` is `None`-y, which is kinda strange in this context.